# Tooltipster not showing on initial hover

Tags: javascript

I am using tooltipster for th3 first time.
https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster

I have this code

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.doreming-task', function(e) {
            var documentWidth = $(document).width();
            var documentHeight = $(document).height();
            var currentID = $(this).attr("event_id");
            var atr = scheduler.getEvent(currentID);
            var taskTitle = atr.text;
            var taskDesc = atr.description;
            var taskstartDuration = atr.start_date;
            var taskendDuration = atr.end_date;

            var taskdatetimeduration = scheduler.templates.tooltip_date_format(taskstartDuration).split(" ")[1] + " " + scheduler.templates.tooltip_date_format(taskstartDuration).split(" ")[2] + " - " +
                scheduler.templates.tooltip_date_format(taskendDuration).split(" ")[1] + " " + scheduler.templates.tooltip_date_format(taskendDuration).split(" ")[2];

            var taskAssign = atr.person;
            var taskProject = atr.project_id;
            var taskGroup = atr.management_id;
            var taskLocation = atr.work_location_name;
            var taskContent = atr.work_category;

            var contents_name = "";
            var management_name = "";

            $.each(workContentsHolder, function(key, val) {
                if (taskContent == val['id']) {
                    contents_name = val['name'];
                    return false;
                } else {
                    contents_name = " ";
                }
            });
            $.each(departmentHolder, function(key, val) {
                if (taskGroup == val['id']) {
                    management_name = val['name'];
                    return false;
                } else {
                    management_name = " ";
                }
            });


            $("#task-title-holder").text(taskTitle);
            $("#task-duration").text(taskdatetimeduration);
            $("#task-description-holder").text(taskDesc);
            $("#task-assign-holder").text(taskAssign);
            $("#task-project-holder").text(taskProject);
            $("#task-group-holder").text(management_name);
            $("#work-content-holder").text(contents_name);
            $("#work-location-holder").text(taskLocation);

            $(this).tooltipster({
                animation: "fade",
                delay: 100,
                trigger: 'hover',
                content: $('#tooltip_content'),
                arrow: false,
                contentAsHTML: true,
                repositionOnScroll: true,
                trackTooltip: true,
                contentCloning: true,
                theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
                multiple: false,
            })
        });
```

Basically, I just get the "event_id", get all the details, append in the HTML holder and put it on the content, it is working fine but it is always on the second hover

Any help and assistance will be appeciated

Comment: Because you don't set it up until the first hover. If you want it before do the tooltipster() call outside the mouseenter

Comment: Hi! Patrick, I try to initialize it before mouse enter, and it is not showing even on second hover